# how can ı say ı like watching series

Tags: translation, english-to-german

how can ı say ı like watching series using  gerne

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Please see the above and [edit] your question accordingly: Tell us what you already know and where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can say,

> Ich schaue gerne Serien

or in everyday language,

> Ich gucke gerne Serien